# Prove that $S_3\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ is isomorphic to $D_6$

Tags: group-theory

Prove that $S_3\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ is isomorphic to $D_6$.

**My attempt:**

I tried to decompose $D_6$ as the internal direct product of subgroups $H$ and $K$ isomorphic to $S_3$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2$ respectively:

Let $H=\{1, r^2, r^4, s, r^2s, r^4s\}$

Let $K=\{1, r^3s\}$

$HK=D_6$

$H\cap K=\{1\}$

However, taking $h=r^2$ and $k=r^3s$,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
hk&=r^2\cdot r^3s \\
&=r^5s
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
kh&=r^3s\cdot r^2 \\
&=r^3sr^2ss \\
&=r^3r^{-2}s \\
&= rs
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
$hk\neq kh$

So, this doesn't work. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $Z(D_6) = \langle r^3\rangle$. This is your candidate for the copy of $C_2$.